# mdmsoft/yii2-admin module not working in basic templet

Tags: yii2

I am new with yii n am trying to include an admin module "mdmsoft/yii2-admin" in my app i have followed the readme instructions from https://github.com/mdmsoft/yii2-admin/tree/master/#rbac-manager-for-yii-2,there is no error in installation but when i try to open the admin page by mydomain/web.php/admin" its showing "Not Found". I have also checked the root permission of all the files and folders in the application and it is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mydomain/web.php/admin` should be `mydomain/web/admin`.

Comment: I did the configuration wrong that is why it was not working...thanks any way.